# java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, weblogic12c, oracle12c

I am uploading two data files one after the other into a table, and while doing so I keep getting error as below. Yes, I am not cancelling any process in the middle.

PS: I am using JDeveloper 12c and the internal 12c Weblogic server to deploy my application.

```
Exception ::com.ofss.pm.upload.common.exception.UploadException: UploadException in parsePopulateBrnBnkUpld :com.ofss.pm.upload.common.exception.UploadException: SQLException : 
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 148
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 889
ORA-06512: at line 1

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:466)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:407)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1113)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:603)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:228)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:49)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1000)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1316)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5010)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5136)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:10886)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1519)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:170)
at com.ofss.pm.upload.dao.BranchBankDao.callProcUpldBranchBank(BranchBankDao.java:614)
at com.ofss.pm.upload.handler.BranchBankHandler.parsePopulateBrnBnkUpld(BranchBankHandler.java:113)
at com.ofss.pm.scheduler.jobs.BranchBankUpldJob.execute(BranchBankUpldJob.java:78)
at com.ofss.pm.scheduler.JobExecutorBean.onMessage(JobExecutorBean.java:264)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:438)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:361)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:297)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:5107)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4775)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:4170)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:127)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5627)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Aks your DBA - could be that your DBA has defined some resource limits for your account. See `CREATE PROFILE` command here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310 there is `CPU_PER_CALL` parameter there, this parameter limits a total time of each call, if a query time exceeds this limit, then ORA-01013 occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I had to change the Statement Timeout setting in the Weblogic console to 0 instead of -1 to avoid going into timeout error.